# How do I subtract coins in my game when the user buys in game items in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Im having trouble subtracting the total coins in my game when the user purchases an item. I have this character that costs 250 and I want to minus the 250 from the total coins I have but it doesn't work What am I doing wrong?

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

    var touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if node.name == "buyItem" {
        var defaults=NSUserDefaults()
        var coinScore = defaults.integerForKey("coinScore")


        if coinScore >= 250 {

        //Im using this to subtract the coins from the total coins but it doesn't subtract when I press on the button. 

        coinScore - 250

        //These 4 lines are to unlock the character and get rid of the button

        NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "unlock250")
        yellowImage.removeFromParent()
        unlockYellowImage()
        yellowButton.removeFromParent()

        }

    }

 }
```

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but `touchesBegan` also seems like a strange place to initiate this kind of action; if doing it manually it should probably be in `touchesEnded` so that it triggers on finger up instead of finger down, but most of the time you should be using either the action of a button or a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Thanks thats really helpful Im going to do that right now! Also I got it to save. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coinScore - 250` simply calculates the subtraction, but the result is not assigned anywhere. You need to do `coinScore = coinScore - 250`, which can be written as `coinScore -= 250`.

Furthermore, you then need to store it back in `defaults` if you wish the updated value to be read the next time you do `defaults.integerForKey("coinScore")`. Use `defaults.setInteger(coinScore, forKey: "coinScore")`.

It also seems likely that you should be using `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` instead of `NSUserDefaults()`.

Comment: I got it to minus and Im gonna try to save it now

Answer (score 0):

you have to write a custom function that gets called whenever you want to subtract coins from your UserDefaults Data I have been searching as well for something like this and when I got the idea on how to do it I wrote my own custom function for it

this should also work in Swift 3

```
var unlocked = UserDefaults().bool(forKey: "Unlocked")
var price = 0

func PurchaseBtnClicked() {
    func deductCoins() -> Bool {

        if price > coins {
            print("not enough coins")
            return false
        }
        if coins > price {
            coins = coins - price
            UserDefaults.standard.set(coins, forKey: "Coins")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "Unlocked")
            return true
        }

        return true
    }
    price = 250 //make sure to set the price here before the deductCoins() function is called otherwise you may over/underprice the user
    deductCoins()
    crowBackBtn.removeFromSuperview()
    crowPurchaseBtn.removeFromSuperview()
}
func BackBtnClicked() {
    crowBackBtn.removeFromSuperview()
    crowPurchaseBtn.removeFromSuperview()
}
if UserDefaults().bool(forKey "Unlocked") == true {//this is called when the boolean value unlocked is saved as true
    print("content is already unlocked")
    //here I want to push the viewController to another viewController so the user can view the content he/she has bought
} else {
    //in here is where I will add my prompt label and a button to confirm the purchase 
        PurchaseBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "yesImage"), for: .normal)
        PurchaseBtn.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width / 3, y: view.frame.size.height / 2, width: 90, height: 30)
        PurchaseBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.PurchaseBtnClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        BackBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "noImage"), for: .normal)
        BackBtn.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width / 3, y: view.frame.size.height / 1.7, width: 90, height: 30)
        BackBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.BackBtnClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(PurchaseBtn)
        self.view.addSubview(BackBtn)    
}
```

you should be able to copy and paste the above code just be sure to change the images it will only work once though as the item will be purchased as soon as the PurchaseBtn is pressed

**-EDIT-**

oh shoot I just realized in reviewing this that I posted this meant for a viewController not the GameScene